# Is plan for my django models correct?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am working on simple keyword tool that has 2-3 tables/classes. Here is my plan, would you recommend any changes to the structure ? Is it even correct?;

---

**Table 1(keyword is the id, difficulty is taken from table2):**

- Keyword
- Searches
- cpc
- competition
- difficulty(foreign key)

---

**Table 2(use keyword from table1, get googles top10 results for it, save difficulty):**

- Keyword(foreign key)
- url_1
- url_2
- url_3
- url_4
- Difficulty(ManyToMany if i store data in table3, otherwise int)

---

I plan on storing ~5 things for each url that will be used to perform calculations later on, what would be best way to store them? I am thinking in Table2 in json format ?

Cheers

Comment: It is not clear to me what is you requirements. What is *cpc*? What is *competition*? What do the urls represent?

Comment: What is the reason to have both fields (`keyword` and `difficulty`) in each model?

Comment: What are your requirements? What would you do?